# Button onclick doesn't change style.display of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I have two `div`s, called `loginpending` and `loggedin`, which I am trying to configure so that once a button (`button`) is clicked, the `div`s will "flicker" between one being on and one being off.

For example, in this current state (with `loginpending`'s display as `block` and `loggedin`'s display as `none`), once the button is clicked, `loginpending`'s display will become `none` and `loggedin`'s display will become `block` through the function `loginUpdate`, which is then called through `launch` depending on what the state of each `div` is.

However, it doesn't work - the state of the buttons don't change at all once the button is clicked.

Help!

HTML code:

```
<div id="loginpending" style="display:block;">
  <a href="login.html">Signup</a>/<a href="login.html">Login</a> here!
</div>
<div id="loggedin" style="display:none;">
  Hello!
</div>
<button id="button" onclick="launch()">Hello!</button>
```

Javascript code (with Jquery):

```
var logincheck = 0;

function loginUpdate() {
  "use strict";
  $("#loginpending").toggle();
  $("#loggedin").toggle();
}

function launch() {
  "use strict";
  var loginpending = document.getElementById("loginpending").style.display;
  var loggedin = document.getElementById("loggedin").style.display;
  window.alert(loginpending);
  window.alert(loggedin);
  if (loginpending === "none") {
    logincheck = 0;
    loginUpdate();
  } else if (loggedin === "none") {
    logincheck = 1;
    loginUpdate();
  } else {
    logincheck = 0;
    $("#loggedin").toggle();
  }
}
```

Comment: You dont need `launch` function. directly call `loginUpdate` function

Comment: did you import jquery library? It runs with no problem in my machin when I did the import

Comment: @Jack Yes, I did. Should I include that piece of code?

Comment: Open your browser's console, and show out the error

Comment: There is no error, which is the weird thing. However, the solutions below work, so I'm probably going to use them.

Comment: I got it, your page is not html, may be jsp or apsx. right?

Comment: @Jack What is jsp and apsx?

Answer (score 0):

Right now your `button` is `submitting` the `from` which `refreshes` the page `reloads`in its original state.

You need to set the `type` of button to `type="button"`

```
<button id="button" type="button" onclick="launch()">Hello!</button>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! So, what exactly does the `type="button"` do? Is the default different?

Comment: `type="button"` doesn't submit the form and calls the function which you have called on that button click.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function(){
     $('div').toggleClass('hidden');
    })
});
```

```css
    
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="loginpending" class="">
        <a href="login.html">Signup</a>/<a href="login.html">Login</a> here!
    </div>
    <div id="loggedin" class="hidden">
        Hello!
    </div>
    <button id="button" onclick="">Hello!</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Code with jQuery

Comment: It works, but I'm probably going to use the other solutions - mainly because it's simpler.

Comment: no problem :)
I have provide in jQuery
The other one is in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use your original code as much as I could.

```js
var logincheck = 0;

$("#button").click(function() {
 launch();
});

function loginUpdate() {
  "use strict";
  $("#loginpending").toggle();
  $("#loggedin").toggle();
}

function launch() {
  "use strict";
  var loginpending = $("#loginpending").is(":hidden");
  var loggedin = $("#loggedin").is(":hidden");
  
  if(loginpending)
   logincheck = 0;
  else if (loggedin)
   logincheck = 1
  else
   logincheck = 0;
    
  loginUpdate();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loginpending" style="display:block;">
  <a href="login.html">Signup</a>/<a href="login.html">Login</a> here!
</div>
<div id="loggedin" style="display:none;">
  Hello!
</div>
<button id="button" type="button">Hello!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, why is there no curly brackets around the if/else?

Comment: because there is just one statement after if/else

Comment: Like @Jack mentioned, if you only have one line of code after an `if` or `else`, you don't have to write curly brackets. It doesn't hurt to put them, if you wanna be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta try this

```js
$(function() {
 var logincheck = 0;
 function loginUpdate() {
    "use strict";
    $("#loginpending").toggle();
    $("#loggedin").toggle();
  }
  
 $('#button').on('click', function(){
   "use strict";
    if(logincheck == 0) {
      logincheck = 1;
    }else{
     logincheck = 0;
    }
    loginUpdate();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loginpending" style="display:block;">
  <a href="login.html">Signup</a>/<a href="login.html">Login</a> here!
</div>
<div id="loggedin" style="display:none;">
  Hello!
</div>
<button id="button">Hello!</button>
```